# my postgresql table ignores the time part of the date time column

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime

my table has a column defines like so 
`myDate TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT now()`,

my model looks like so: `myDate= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)`

my Django function writes to the model like so:

```
import datetime

for key, value in request_data['xx'].iteritems():
    rec , created = myTable.objects.get_or_create(myDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(value['theDateTime'])
    rec.save()
```

debugging with a `print` command print the date time correctly `2014-09-25 18:06:23` but in myTable the date time is stored like this `2014-09-25 00:00:00`

Comment: how is your model field defined ?

Comment: @karthikr myDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)